# unsigned int - shifting and oring creates negative value

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am reading the header of a `wav` file and filling my class-members using `<<` (left-shift) and `|` (or) as I read the raw bytes from file. Now, coincidently I have the following situation
where `uBytesPerSecond` is of type `unsigned` and `data` is of `char*` so I can use `std::fstream::read`.

Now when I follow the creation of `uBytesPerSecond` in the debugger

```
this->uBytesPerSecond |= data[0x1F]; //0x00 ->uBytesPerSecond = 0x00000000
this->uBytesPerSecond <<= 8;         //     ->uBytesPerSecond = 0x00000000
this->uBytesPerSecond |= data[0x1E]; //0x02 ->uBytesPerSecond = 0x00000002
this->uBytesPerSecond <<= 8;         //     ->uBytesPerSecond = 0x00000200
this->uBytesPerSecond |= data[0x1D]; //0xb1 ->uBytesPerSecond = 0xffffffb1 !!!
this->uBytesPerSecond <<= 8;         //     ->uBytesPerSecond = 0xffffb100
this->uBytesPerSecond |= data[0x1C]; //0x10 ->uBytesPerSecond = 0xffffb110
```

The expected output in this case is `uBytesPerSecond = 0x00002b110`. Please tell what is going here and how I can solve this.

I am using `MSVC2012` and Windows 8, this is a `VC++-Console`-application.

Comment: Without the contain of the `data` it is hard to say what is going wrong.

Comment: Please look at the comments `//` on each line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that for your platform `char` is a signed type. Therefore the contained value will be sign extended to 32bit for the or-operation, giving you `0xffffffb1` for `data[0x1D]`.

To solve that problem simply change the type of `data` to `unsigned char*`.

**Edit:** As noted in the comments, another solution for the problem would be to explicitly mask the operand with `0xFF`: `this->uBytesPerSecond |= data[0x1F] & 0xFF` and so on.

Comment: Okay, this sounds good, but two things: I have seen something about masking like `& 0xFF`, does this help? Secondly what happens to `fstream::read`, because it expects `char*` as a buffer.

Comment: @bash.d: Yes, masking with `data[...] & 0xFF` would work as well (as long as `char` is 8bit, which is a safe asumption for common platforms nowadays. Regarding the `fstream::read`: Well, you could `reinterpret_cast` from `char*` to `unsigned char*` (or the other way around). However using explicit masking might be the cleaner solution, since `reinterpret_cast` is always somewhat iffy (although it should be fine, since the standard has explicit axceptions to strict aliasing when it comes to `char*`

Comment: Careful with the masks. If you mask a char with 0xFF it might still be sign extended because at that point the expression is still a char. It would be preferable to do a `static_cast<unsigned char>()`.

Comment: @OliverD: How so, considering `0xFF` is of type `int`? It would sign extend `data[...]` before the mask operation, only to get rid of the sign extension using the and.

Comment: @Grizzly My bad. I was under the impression 0xFF was a char or constant. I think 0x00FF or 0x000000FF would make the intent clearer in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a union instead of messing around with bitwise-or and shifts? Something like

```
union ByteWord
{
    unsigned int word;
    char bytes[sizeof(unsigned int)];
}
```

Then you can just do

```
ByteWord data;
myStream.read(data.bytes, sizeof(unsigned int));
this->uBytesPerSecond = myStream.word;
```

Use `ntohl(myStream.word)` if you need it byte-swapped.

Comment: It was more of a general question, but thank you for your effort.

Comment: Wouldn't that technically invoke undefined behaviour (reading from a union element you have not previously written to)? Most compilers do make special exceptions for that, but it might still be desierable to be truely conformant, particulary if portablility on a wide range of platforms is desired (who knows when you get a compiler not supporting that).

Comment: @Grizzly not sure I follow you. This code reads from the stream and writes to the union. It doesn't write to the same field we read from, ok. However I thought that was the whole point of unions: unlike a struct the fields share memory. If you refer to the read failing, I agree it should be checked. I was going for conciseness.

Comment: @OliverD: The fields share the memory, that much is true. However the C++ Standard forbids reading from a union field that has not been previously written to (only one field is active at a time). As mentioned in practice most compilers make guarantees for this to work, but unless I'm missing something in the standard this is not valid standard c++ code.

Comment: @Grizzly I wasn't aware of this. Thanks for the enlightenment.